# Spark Structured Streaming inconsistent output to multiple sinks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I am using spark structured streaming to read data from Kafka and apply some udf to the dataset. The code as below :

```
calludf = F.udf(lambda x: function_name(x))

dfraw = spark.readStream.format('kafka') \
    .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', KAFKA_CONSUMER_IP) \
    .option('subscribe', topic_name) \
    .load()
df = dfraw.withColumn("value", F.col('value').cast('string')).withColumn('value', calludf(F.col('value')))

ds = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
    .writeStream \
    .format('console') \
    .option('truncate', False) \
    .start()

dsf = df.selectExpr("CAST (value AS STRING)") \
    .writeStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_CONSUMER_IP) \
    .option("topic", topic_name_two) \
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_location) \
    .start()

ds.awaitTermination()
dsf.awaitTermination()
```

Now the problem is that I am getting 10 dataframes as input. 2 of them failed due to some issue with the data which is understandable. The console displays rest of the 8 processed dataframes BUT only 6 of those 8 processed dataframes are written to the Kafka topic using ***dsf*** steaming query. Even though I have added checkpoint location to it but it is still not working.

*PS: Do let me know if you have any suggestion regarding the code as well. I am new to spark structured streaming so maybe there is something wrong with the way I am doing it.*